# Calling or communicating with docker container on one machine from other application not in docker container and in another machine

Tags: linux, docker, flask

I have my docker container in one machine running say Machine A. I have another machine B which consists of a flask server. I would like to call/communicate with the docker container in machine A from my flask server in Machine B. I am not running my flask server inside any docker container. I am actually very new to docker so I am not sure whether we are able to achieve it or not.

Comment: Which kind of communication? Http? Then, what prevents you to communicate with direct url visit like curl?

Comment: Yes, an http request from machine B to machine A

Comment: So, the server side has a `http://` url, as I said, what prevents you to visit with this `http//xxx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just directly visit the http service in container from other machine.

E.g.

Container on machineA was this:

```
docker run -idt -p 9000:80 nginx
```

Then, you machineB's flask application, you can just use:

```
requests.get("http://your_machine_a_ip:9000")
```

to get what you need.

Just remember, for container, you need to expose http port to host, so other machine could visit it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do with your docker container from the flask server, but I am assuming that it would be an API or some service running in the docker container which you want to use in the flask server. You can do so by using the IP of machine A on which docker container is running, also, you will need to bind your docker container's port to the host machine's ( machine A) port. So that whenever you try to reach the host machine on that specific port, you will be calling the containers port instead.
If you want to execute a command in the running container then there are 2 ways to do so, first, you can SSH to the container, second you can SSH to the host machine and then use `docker exec`. But since you are trying to communicate from a flask server, I think that this might not be the case.

Comment: As you said, I would like to run a service in docker container and would like to make an http request from flask server to the docker container. The service would provide me with the output which I can again use in my flask.

Comment: Okay, then you can use the machine A's IP to communicate with the docker, it's just that you need to bind the ports of the container and the host machine. Let's say your service is running on port 9000 of the docker container, then you need to bind port 9000 with some port, let's say 8000 of the host machine. Now if you do an http request on port 8000 of machine A, you will be calling the containers port 9000 instead.